# Dictionary search with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

we can search dictionary like

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dictionary.Keys.Where( key => key.Contains("a")).ToList();
```

but it return list. i want that linq should return  true or false. so what would be the right code that search dictionary with linq. please guide.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `Any()` operator:

```
dictionary.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains("a")).Any();
```

Or

```
dictionary.Keys.Any(key => key.Contains("a"));
```

Comment: this is will return true or false?

Comment: It will return true if there are any values in the set.

Comment: This also works with `dictionary.Values.Any(v => v == 'foo' )`

Answer (score 9):

Use `Any` **instead of** `Where`:

```
dictionary.Keys.Any( key => key.Contains("a"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the .Any() keyword:

```
bool exists = dictionary.Keys.Any(key => key.Contains("a"));
```

Comment: You don't want the `.ToList()` at the end there, since `Any()` returns `bool`, not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can determine whether or not any key in the dictionary contains `"a"`, then you can do:

```
dictionary.Keys.Any(key => key.Contains("a"))
```